# Cannot get API to work when testing in Insomnia

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs

I am brand new to backend development and working on my first project. I am using React Node.js and MySQL. When I go to test my API in Insomnia I keep getting "Error: Couldn't connect to server". I entered POST type and the URL is http://localhost:8900/api/auth/register.Could someone help me find out what I did wrong?

I tried entering ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH
mysql_native_password BY 'abcabc'; in each table I was using in MySQL

My code files are below:

Index.js

```
import express from 'express';
const app = express();
import userRoutes from "./routes/auth.js"
import userRoutes from "./routes/users.js"
import userRoutes from "./routes/posts.js"

app.use(express.json())


app.use("/api/auth", userRoutes)
app.use("/api/users", userRoutes)
app.use("/api/posts", userRoutes)

app.listen(8900, ()=>{
    console.log("API working!")
});
```

Auth.js in my controllers file:

```
import { db } from "../connect.js";
import bcrypt from "bcryptjs";


export const register = (req, res) => {
  //CHECK USER IF EXISTS

  const q = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?";

  db.query(q, [req.body.username], (err, data) => {
    if (err) return res.status(500).json(err);
    if (data.length) return res.status(409).json("User already exists!");
    //CREATE A NEW USER
    //Hash the password
    const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
    const hashedPassword = bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, salt);

    const q =
      "INSERT INTO users (`username`,`email`,`password`,`name`) VALUE (?)";

    const values = [
      req.body.username,
      req.body.email,
      hashedPassword,
      req.body.name,
    ];

    db.query(q, [values], (err, data) => {
      if (err) return res.status(500).json(err);
      return res.status(200).json("User has been created.");
    });
  });
};


export const login =(req, res)=>{

}



export const logout = (req,res)=>{

}
```

Auth.js in my roots folfer:

```
import express from "express";
import { login, register, logout } from "../controllers/auth.js";

const router = express.Router()

router.post("/login", login)
router.post("/register", register)
router.post("/logout", logout)

export default router
```

connect.js in my routes folder:

```
import mysql from "mysql"


export const db = mysql.createConnection(
    {
        host:"localhost",
        user:"root",
        password:"abcabc",
        database: "social"
    }
)
```

users.js in routes folder:

```
import express from "express";
import { getUser } from "../controllers/user.js";

const router = express.Router()

router.get("/find:userId", getUser)

export default router
```

posts.js in routes:

```
import express from "express";
import { getPosts } from "../controllers/post.js";

const router = express.Router();

router.get("/", getPosts);


export default router;
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You get this error when insomnia can't get any response from the server when it sends the data. I can't find any weird things in your code (maybe I'm not looking correct) other than that all Routes variables are called the same. So can you check if your server is running and change those things?

Answer (score 0):

your code is ok you can do one thing just simply go to the terminal inside which

```
node your file.js
```

And then

`npm start` and then refresh ( I mean send ) your insomnia

this will probably help you cause it helped me as well